# SQL loader: join on other table

Tags: oracle, join, sql-loader

I just went through the online documentations, and found that when using SQL loader to load flat files, if you wish to make join on another table in order to get values from that table. It is not possible. We need to use external tables in this approach. Please confirm if this is true. Is there any way we can join another table when using SQL loaders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true.  You could load into a staging table, and then after the load run a procedure that selects from that and joins to another table.  Or you could change to using an external table, which is generally to be preferred.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this understanding :)

Answer (score 1):

There is one workaround for cases with small number of foreign key's values.
And values are predefined :)
For example, we have reference table with records

```
ID Color
--------
1  Red
2  Blue
3  Green
```

and load a flat file that has the column "Color" with string values (Red, Blue and Green).
We want to make column "color_id" in a destination table and use IDs of colors.

```
color FILLER,
:color_id "decode(:field2, 1, 'Red', 2, 'Blue', 3, 'Green')",
```

Comment: Thanks knagaev for the help. But this is not my requirement. I need to make join on another table and fetch values from that table.